# Prevent Html.ActionLink adding route values automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a action link setup like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Orders", "Index", "Order")
```

When I am on the page http://mydomain.com/Order/Index/2 that action link becomes a link to the page that I am on.  How do I make it always link to http://mydomain.com/Order/Index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because routing engine reuses route variables from the current request. To prevent it from happening, you should always supply value for route variable.

```
    //assuming that last /2 corresponds to route variable named id

    @Html.ActionLink("Orders", "Index", "Order", new {id = ""}, null)
```

Comment: I tried null instead of new {id=""} previously but that didnt work

Comment: null means value is not supplied. It is default value in fact - that anonymous object is translated into RouteValueDictionary. And it returns null if the key was not found in it - so no difference if you supply null or do not supply value at all

Comment: This seems very counter-intuitive. I would not expect it to do this. I wonder if there's a way to configure the routing engine.